# How to make the submenu leave first, and then padding the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

How to make sure that when you click on the "Menu with sub" item, the submenu first goes out, and then padding appears in the body? And when you hide all submenu at first, and then you already lost the padding body? Now there is a white gap there...........................................................................................................................

My full menu is here: [menu as CodePen](https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/xaLpLv)

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
var menuWrap = $('.js-nav');
var rootMenu = menuWrap.children('.js-menu');
var currentMenu = rootMenu;

function setMenu(menu) {
    var level = menu.parents('.js-menu').length;

    menu.show();
    menuWrap.css('height', menu.outerHeight());
    rootMenu.css('left', -100 * level + '%');
    currentMenu = menu;

    if (rootMenu.css('transitionDuration') !== '0s') {
        rootMenu.one('transitionend', function(){
            menu.find('.js-menu').show();
        });
    } else {
        menu.find('.js-menu').show();
    }
}

var linkOfSubMenu = $('.js-link-sub');

function clickToLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var findMenu = $(this).parent().siblings('.js-menu');
    setMenu(findMenu);
}

var hamburgerIcon = $('.js-hamburger');
var mnuWrap = $('.js-nav');

function huburgIcon(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('m-hamburger-active');
    mnuWrap.toggleClass('m-nav-opened');
    mnuWrap.removeAttr('style');

    var previousMenu = currentMenu.parent('li').parent('.js-menu');
    setMenu(previousMenu);
}

var subHeight = $('.js-menu-drop').outerHeight();

function subMenuDesktop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sub = $(this).parent().next(); 
  sub.slideDown(600);
  $('body').css({
    paddingTop: subHeight
  })
}

var hideBtn = $('.js-hide'); 

function hideButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').css({
        paddingTop: 0
    });
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().slideUp(600);
}




var mediaQueryXS = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)');

function onResize(mediaQueryXS) {
    if (mediaQueryXS.matches) {
        hamburgerIcon.on('click', huburgIcon);
        linkOfSubMenu.on('click', clickToLink);

        linkOfSubMenu.off('click', subMenuDesktop);

        $('body').removeAttr('style');

        hideBtn.off('click', hideButton);

    } else {
        hamburgerIcon.off('click', huburgIcon);
        linkOfSubMenu.off('click', clickToLink);

        linkOfSubMenu.on('click', subMenuDesktop);

        hideBtn.on('click', hideButton);
    }
}

onResize(mediaQueryXS);
mediaQueryXS.addListener(onResize); 
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="head-top js-head">

        <a href="#" class="hamburger js-hamburger">Open me</a>

        <nav class="nav js-nav">
            <ul class="menu js-menu">
                <li> 
                    <h4><a href="">Lomrem 1</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <h4><a href="">Lomrem 2</a></h4>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h4><a class="js-link-sub" href="#">Menu with sub</a></h4>
                    <ul class="menu menu_dropdown js-menu js-menu-drop">
                        <li class="subMenu-items">
                            <ul class="subMenu-list">
                                <li class="subMenu-box">
                                    <ul class="subMenu-item">
                                        <li>
                                            <h4><a href="#" >Lorem 3.1</a></h4>
                                            <ul class="subMenu-points">
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="subMenu-box">
                                    <ul class="subMenu-item">
                                        <li>
                                            <h4><a href="#" >Lorem 3.2</a></h4>
                                            <ul class="subMenu-points">
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="subMenu-box">
                                    <ul class="subMenu-item">
                                        <li>
                                            <h4><a href="#" >Lorem 3.3</a></h4>
                                            <ul class="subMenu-points">
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="hide js-hide">
                                    Hide
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your essential HTML, so that other users can help you easier. Thanks!

Comment: Hello! My html code is here: [code](https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/xaLpLv)

Comment: Thanks, according to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I added the HTML directly to the question.